# interactive ssh connection forgetting/creating keystrokes

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

By and then it happens to me, that an ssh session running on WSL/windows11/ubuntu_20.04 to Centos 7.9 forgets keystrokes or other keystrokes are suddenly repeated. This is driving me crazy!

And I'm thinking naively, that nobody could be sufficiently stupid to use a datagram socket for implementing a ssh connection. I mean, I would not mind, if there is a delay for my keystrokes but forgetting keystrokes or creating a series of strokes out of one is driving me nuts.

Anybody knows the fix for this?

Could this be caused by zscaler?